# If Content-Type is image-like do something, elif is text/html then do something else. How to do this?

Tags: python, django

first of all, I'm apology for the title. I dont know how to explain this so i write the title like this.

I want to check the Content-Type and if it is image/ run these code

```
from PIL import Image
import io, uuid, requests

class LinkCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        headers = {'content-type': 'image/'}
        r = requests.get(form.instance.url, headers=headers)
        i = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content)).convert('RGB')
        image_io = io.BytesIO()
        try:
            crop_image = ImageOps.fit(i, method=Image.ANTIALIAS, size=(65, 65), bleed=0.5, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
            hash = str(uuid.uuid1())
            name = "{}.jpeg".format(hash)
            crop_image.save(image_io, format="jpeg")
            form.instance.img.save(name, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))
        finally:
            image_io.close()

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.rank_score = 0.0
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()

        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

If it is text/html then run these code;

```
from PIL import Image
import io, uuid, requests, lxml.html

url = ("http://website.com")
page = requests.get(url)
hash = str(uuid.uuid1())
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
og = tree.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:image"][1]/@content')
r = requests.get(og[0])
i = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content)).convert('RGB')
crop_image = ImageOps.fit(i, method=Image.ANTIALIAS, size=(65,65), bleed=0.5, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
crop_image.save("{}.jpeg".format(hash))
```

I tried if, else things but it didn't work. I dont know how to implement this second piece of code to first one. Both code work perfectly by itself.

I tried like these code:

```
if page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html:
    .....
elif page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'image/':
    .....
```

Thanks to LearnerEarner my problem is solved. Working code is below

```
class LinkCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        r = requests.get(form.instance.url)
        image_io = io.BytesIO()
        hash = str(uuid.uuid1())
        try:
            if r.headers['Content-Type'].startswith("image/"):
                i = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content)).convert('RGB')
                crop_image = ImageOps.fit(i, method=Image.ANTIALIAS, size=(65, 65), bleed=0.5, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
                name = "{}.jpeg".format(hash)
                crop_image.save(image_io, format="jpeg")
                form.instance.img.save(name, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))
            elif r.headers['Content-Type'].startswith("text/html"):
                tree = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
                og = tree.xpath('/html/head/meta[@property="og:image"][1]/@content')
                r = requests.get(og[0])
                i = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content)).convert('RGB')
                crop_image = ImageOps.fit(i, method=Image.ANTIALIAS, size=(65, 65), bleed=0.5, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
                name = "{}.jpeg".format(hash)
                crop_image.save(image_io, format="jpeg")
                form.instance.img.save(name, ContentFile(image_io.getvalue()))
        finally:
            image_io.close()

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.rank_score = 0.0
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()

        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: A couple of points.  First, you should give a little  more context, and some sample URLs, etc.  For example, what do I need to import for this?  Second, I am puzzled as to what you mean by "I tried if, else things".  If should be a straightforward if page.headers['content-type'] = type thing...

Comment: @SteveCohen I updated the question. What i mean is i tried these code. Like: page.header['content-type]' == 'text/html'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried like these code:
>
> ```
> if page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html:
>     .....
> elif page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'image/':
>     .....
> ```

As far as my knowledge goes there is no generic Content-Type like 'image/'(unless you are explicitly sending such Content-Type in response headers).  The MIME Type has to be specific.

Print and observe the response headers from your `requests.get` to see the exact Content-Type before you use it in the else condition.

If all that you expect are HTML and images, you need not have a specific condition for images.  You can try something like this:

```
if page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html':
    ....
else:
    try:
        #treat it as image and proceed
    except:
        #may be not an image
```

OR

You can do this:

```
if page.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/html:
    .....
elif page.headers['Content-Type'].startswith("image/"):
    .....
```

Please refer to this [list for MIME Types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/).

Comment: Yes but i dont want to just the specific type. I want to image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif etc.

Comment: @Yunus Edited the answer with a generic way of checking image Content-Type

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved. I updated my question with working code.

Comment: @Yunus Nice. you are wc.  One suggestion, If you can, it would be better to manage the conditional check with "==" comparison in if statement.  There is no need to use startswith() if you want to compare the whole string like "text/html"

Comment: If i just do == 'text/html' code isn't working. I changed the 'text/html' to 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'' then code is working. 

The part of "charset=UTF-8" maybe changeable. What do you think? Is the default charset for all web sites?

Comment: You are right.  charset is not uncommon.  https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index

Comment: Hım. Should I continue with this? or Is there any better option to startswith()

Comment: Continuing with startswith() should be fine

Comment: Okay. Thanks again :)